# AngularJS Ng-Repeat only on sub-child row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Having this JavaScript object literal in a controller variable:

```
this.data = [{
    name: '1',
    children: [{
        name: '11',
        children: [{
            name: '111'}, {
            name: '112'}]}, {
        name: '12',
        children: [{
            name: '121'}, {
            name: '122'}]}]}, {
    name: '2',
    children: [{
        name: '21'}, {
        name: '22'}]}];
```

How can I render into view only the **children.children.name** (s) ? 
I know ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end but i think it doesn't help me.

I've read of the possibility of defining a custom directive with no "html value" template, but this solution seems ugly.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a nested ng-repeat on the client side.

```
<div ng-repeat="dataItem in data">
  <div ng-repeat="children in dataItem.children">
     <div ng-repeat="grandChildren in children.children">
          <span>{{grandChildren.name}}</span>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This might not be what you wanted but I hope it gives you enough ideas to go through with what you want to do. Best of luck!

Comment: No, it doesn't help me. With your html, the result in DOM will be 
<div> <div> <div> <span> Name </span> </div> </div> </div>.
I just want <span> Name </span>